# Counting number of labelled notebooks

Tags: combinatorics

I want to label note books using one letter in the English Alphabet and one number from the set $\lbrace 1, 2, 3,...,100 \rbrace $. For example I can label one notebook $A100$ or $A1$, assumimng that the labels like  $100A$ or $1A$ are not allowed and that each notebook is given only one label, how many notebooks do I need to for me to print  all the possible labels.

Comment: How about $26\cdot100$?

Comment: Would you give the answer in details below @barakmanos

Comment: I honestly can't think of any other details that I can add on top of what I've already mentioned.

Comment: Just few sentences to give reasons why you think the answer is that one @barakmanos

Comment: There are 26 letters possible and 100 numbers.  The "fundamental theorem of counting": if event A can happen in m ways and event B can happen in n ways for every way A happens, then they can happen together in mn ways.  If you are expected to be able to do a problem like this then you are clearly expected to know that!

Comment: Thanks guys, I am satisfied

Comment: You are very organized. On the top shelf of the bookcase you have the notebooks A1 to A100, of course in order, On the second shelf, you have the notebooks B1 to B100. And so on. We have then $26$ shelves, $100$ books on each shelf, total $100+\cdots +100$ ($26$ of them), so $(26)(100)$ notebooks.

Comment: This is very good @AndréNicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$_ _$$
The first space can be filled by $26$ choices. The second one by $100$ choicess. 
$$\text{So by the multiplication principle, 26.100=2600 is the answer}$$

Comment: @barakmanos....